# Webpack Hashing name of files is different

Tags: webpack, deployment, build

Hashing name of files when I run npm run build it generated in different number of the number in index.html file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8M5R.png)

in index.html file code is :

```
   <script src="../src/plugins/common/common.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../src/js/custom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add a comment to get more info but don't have enough rep so I'll answer a bit blindly.

Firstly it depends on what hashing you chose in webpack for your file. I imagine somewhere in your `webpack.common` or `webpack.prod` inside output you might have something like this

```
output: {
  filename: '[contenthash].js',
  ...config
}
```

to keep the filename you should change that to:

```
output: {
  filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
  ...config
}
```

Why does webpack add a hash, or better yet why should you have a hash in your filename?

In short **caching**!

- Having something like `custom.abc123.js` allows the clients browser to invalidate the file in their cache and force it download the new version.
- The `abc123` hash for example could be generated based on the contents of your file, so if you update your code, you file now has a new hash `custom.efg456.js` and the clients browser knows `custom.abc123.js` is now outdated.

Hope that answers why you should use a hash, and potentially why it your project compiled to have one!

Comment: It is my question, but i dont understand how to change a source path in html, when hash filename changes. Some clues? Thanks